# Multiple pointers to another arrays from one Bitmap

Tags: c#, image, pointers, bitmap, marshalling

I have a method to copying `Bitmap` to array of `byte` using `Marshal.Copy`:

```
    public byte[][] PrepareTestSamples(Bitmap bitmap, int imageCount, out BitmapData bitmapData)
    {
        bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            bitmap.PixelFormat);

        int pixelsCount = bitmapData.Stride * bitmap.Height;
        byte[][] images = new byte[imageCount * 3][];

        for (int i = 0; i < imageCount * 3; i++)
        {
            images[i] = new byte[pixelsCount];
            Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, images[i], 0, pixelsCount);
        }

        return images;
    }
```

And this code works perfectly. I can copy image to byte arrays `imageCount * 3` times.

Then im using this arrays to test my algorithms. The definition of any algorithm looks like this:

```
    byte[] Execute(byte[] pixels, int stride, int height, int width);
```

After executing algorithm im returning new `byte[]` with changed pixels. Then i copying it back to new `Bitmap` again using `Lockbits`.

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
           new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
           ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
           bitmap.PixelFormat);

        Marshal.Copy(images[1], 0, bmpData.Scan0, images[1].Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

I want to test my program using `pointers`. I want to check it, if pointers in this case will be faster than managed memory.

I think, that definition of any algorithm must be changed to:

```
byte[] Execute(byte* pixels, int stride, int height, int width);
```

But i have question, how to copy `BitmapData` to something like array of pointers? How to store `imagesCount * 3` images as pointers and pass `pointer` to method one by one?

Comment: Create a structure that contains the stride, height, width, and pixels.  Before the pixels also include the array count.  This makes it easy to create an array of the items.  Then you have an array of bitmapData[].

Comment: it makes sense. Will i have acces to pointers by each `BitmapData` stored in array of `BitmapData`? Its a logic that you are talking about? I need to make (for example) 30 `BitmapData`, pack it to `array` and then acces to each one separatly in each algorithm iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Your code would look something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct BitmapData
        {
            public int stride { get; set; }
            public int height { get; set; }
            public int width { get; set; }
            public long length { get; set; }
            public byte[] pixels { get; set; } 
        }
        public class ManagedBitmapData
        {
            public int stride { get; set; }
            public int height { get; set; }
            public int width { get; set; }
            public long length { get; set; }
            public byte[] pixels { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //source data
            List<ManagedBitmapData> managedData = new List<ManagedBitmapData>();
            IntPtr[] UnmanagedData = new IntPtr[managedData.Count];
            BitmapData[] bitMaps = new BitmapData[managedData.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < managedData.Count; i++)
            {
                bitMaps[i] = new BitmapData();
                bitMaps[i].stride = managedData[i].stride;
                bitMaps[i].height = managedData[i].height;
                bitMaps[i].width = managedData[i].width;
                bitMaps[i].length = managedData[i].length;
                bitMaps[i].pixels = managedData[i].pixels;
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(bitMaps[i], UnmanagedData[i], true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! What about Lockbits and unlocking bits? Why you didnt do Lockbits? Could you provide some explenation of your code, what are you doing and what are you doing?

Comment: A double point like data[][] is really an array of pointers where each pointer points to a the start address of a block of memory of known size.  So when passing the data to a c++ method data[][] is equivalent to IntPrt[] UnmanagedData.  So to pass data to c++ you need to copy each managed memory object (managedData) to unmanaged space (bitMaps).  Then pass to c++ the IntPtr (start address of data) of the unmanaged memory block.